# Is there a diff-buffer-with-file equivalent for Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, diff

Hitherto I've done all my work in Emacs and have become accustomed to `diff-buffer-with-file`, which shows changes that are made in the buffer but have not yet been saved. Is there a similar tool within Microsoft Word?

Comment: It's amazing, really -- three years later and I googled the same question, was elated at a SuperUser post, only to be pulled back down into my own hopelessness :'(